# call multiple async functions in sequential order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
async function unsubscribeUserHandler() {
  const unsubscribe = await fetch("/api/stripe-sessions/cancel-subscription", {
    method: "PATCH",
    body: JSON.stringify(),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await unsubscribe.json();
  if (!unsubscribe.ok) {
    Toast.fire({
      icon: "error",
      title: `${data.message}`,
    });
  } else {
    Toast.fire({
      icon: "success",
      title: `${data.message}`,
    });
  }
}

async function deleteUserHandler() {
  const deleteUser = await fetch("/api/user/delete-account", {
    method: "DELETE",
    body: JSON.stringify(),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await deleteUser.json();
  if (!deleteUser.ok) {
    Toast.fire({
      icon: "error",
      title: `${data.message}`,
    });
  } else {
    Toast.fire({
      icon: "success",
      title: `${data.message}`,
    });
  }
}

const deleteAccount = async () => {
    try {
        await unsubscribeUserHandler();
        await deleteUserHandler();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('ERROR@@@@@!!!',err);
    }
}

const Settings = () => {
  return <DeleteAccount onDeleteAccount={deleteAccount} />;
};
```

As shown here, I want to unsubscribe.. only after the unsub, then run delete handler.

I have issues where It only runs one of the handlers and not the other. Are there other ways to do this?

have tried:

```js
.then(() => deleteUserHandler())
```

and

```js
.then(deleteUserHandler)
```

above doesn't make call to /api/user/delete-account,

only to unsubscribe.

Comment: In `.then(deleteUserHandler())` you are calling deleteUserHandler instantly. Try removing the brackets `.then(deleteUserHandler)`

Comment: @jkoch just tested it-- it unsubscribes the user on Stripe, though doesn't delete the user from DB. Which means it's not handling deleteUserHandler

Comment: Could you take a look on your browsers development tools and check if there are any errors on the console and if the call to `/api/user/delete-account` happens?

Comment: @jkoch call to /api/user/delete-account doesn't happen, only /api/stripe-sessions/cancel-subscription

Comment: If your code has changed since asking your question, please [edit] your post to match. It should definitely be `.then(deleteUserHandler)` or `.then(() => deleteUserHandler())`

Comment: @Phil ok, just tried .then(() => deleteUserHandler())-- it only calls unsub as well.

Comment: If they're async, just `await` each call before moving on? (that's basically what the `await` keyword is for: don't move on until an async function call returns, or a promise resolves. Which is the same thing)

Comment: Are you sure your `unsubscribeUserHandler()` is actually resolving with a successful promise? Is your `catch` logging anything?

Comment: @Phil ok, u r right it was throwing an error that was uncought as the session was being destroyed after deletion. I will update post

Comment: @Phil I just went back and investigated-- I didn't know if it was throwing an error.. as it was destroying the session like I mentioned. It didn't show up in the logs. Otherwise I would've mentioned..

Comment: @Phil chilax phil lol

Comment: In your browser dev-tools, enabled the "Preserve log" option (there's one for _Console_ and _Network_)

Comment: @Phil sorry not everyone on stack over flow is a Staff Software Engineer
like you.. down voting this questions. no wonder stack is super toxic

Comment: @temrb hey, sorry about the comment earlier, it was out of line and I've deleted it (and will delete this one too in a bit). Downvote isn't from me either. I hope the "Preserve log" option helps from missing errors in the future

Comment: The error seems to be coming from `unsubscribeUserHandler` (well technically `_unsubscribeUserHandler`) which makes sense as that would prevent anything further in the promise chain (like `deleteUserHandler`) from executing. What do you see in your dev-tools _Network_ panel? Do you have any logs from your backend API that might provide some clarity on why the request failed?

Comment: @Phil -- ended up solving the issue which was unsubscribe was throwing error bc it was not supposed to be patch to unsubscribe user thx for helping

Comment: Can you please undo your changes to the question. As written at the moment the code in this question has no issues whatsoever and works perfectly. The code as is **always** call each async function correctly in sequential order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```js
const deleteAccount = () => unsubscribeUserHandler()
    .then(deleteUserHandler())
    .catch(console.error);
```

You aren't passing `deleteUserhandler` to `then()`, you are immediately calling it and pass the result to `then()`.

To fix, lose the parenthesis:

```js
const deleteAccount = () => unsubscribeUserHandler()
    .then(deleteUserHandler)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Or use an arrow function:

```js
const deleteAccount = () => unsubscribeUserHandler()
    .then(() => deleteUserHandler())
    .catch(console.error);
```

Or better yet:

```js
const deleteAccount = async () => {
  try {
    await unsubscribeUserHandler();
    await deleteUserHandler();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the last solution and it's only calling /api/stripe-sessions/cancel-subscription, not the /api/user/delete-account-- for which I'm assuming it's still not hitting the delete handler. For which, when I call the delete handler by itself it hits the /api/user/delete-account

Comment: @temrb if `unsubscribeUserHandler` does not throw an error, then `deleteUserHandler` _will_ be called. If not, something else is very wrong.

Comment: u are right, there was an issue with one of my methods preventing the promise to continue.